# Segmentation fault - OpenCV & Qt in Netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, netbeans, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create a face recognition software in C++ using OpenCV 2.4 (to process the data), Netbeans (as my IDE) and Qt Designer 4.8.6 (as my GUI designer).

When I run my code it returns the following error:

> RUN FINISHED; Segmentation fault; core dumped;

This is my code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <qt5/QtWidgets/qwidget.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

What might be the problem here? When I remove `cv::VideoCapture cap(0)`, my program runs without errors so I assume the problem is there.

Comment: Please include the stack trace in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue! You just need to install OpenCV 3.0 instead.